# When Docker build, Github packages throws error

Tags: docker, github, .net-core, package

I am using Github Package for my custom nuget package. When i am building my docker file getting error from Nuget.targets " warning : Please use the --api-key and --source options when publishing to GitHub Packages". I have also nuget.config file in my repo. This integration is working for about 6 months. This error started today.

Anyone have idea about this case ?

```
Step 1/15 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-bionic AS build-env
 ---> 4c8132883147
Step 2/15 : ENV PROJECT_NAME="User.Api"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 788db1b5d2c5
Step 3/15 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d36fff51fe95
Step 4/15 : COPY . ./
 ---> e0a24a5a8f70
Step 5/15 : RUN dotnet restore src/$PROJECT_NAME/$PROJECT_NAME.csproj
 ---> Running in 08f00c27e1b5
  Determining projects to restore...
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.403/NuGet.targets(128,5): warning : Please use the --api-key and --source options when publishing to GitHub Packages
```

My docker file looks like

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-bionic AS build-env

ENV PROJECT_NAME="User.Api"

WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./

#RUN dotnet test
RUN dotnet restore src/$PROJECT_NAME/$PROJECT_NAME.csproj
RUN dotnet publish src/$PROJECT_NAME/$PROJECT_NAME.csproj -c Release -o /app/out
RUN touch /app/scm_metadata.json

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-bionic

#Setup timezone to Europe/Istanbul
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tzdata
ENV TZ Europe/Istanbul

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
COPY --from=build-env /app/scm_metadata.json .

EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "User.Api.dll"]
```

Comment: How does your `dockerfile` and project look like?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I added my docker fille.

Comment: I believe, that you should add nuget source before restore, something like `RUN dotnet nuget add source source_url -n name -u user -p password --store-password-in-clear-text`

Comment: I have already NuGet.config file in my source code. But I also tried that. It's not working :( I am getting only warning. It's not breaking my deployment pipeline.

Comment: I am also getting this although not with docker.

We are building in TC and only pushing our package to GitHub Packages. We use the command line syntax in the push command with no issue.

However from out of the blue somehwhere our dotnet restore calls are complaining about this before we even try and push.

I suspect it might be due to the repo URL being present in the project nuspec?
It certainly feels as if something has changed as this was not an issue until yesterday.

Comment: The error here is so confusing I'm running `dotnet nuget restore`, and it tells me to append parameters when publishing? the -apikey parameter dosen't even exist on `restore`.

Comment: It's fixed today. Probably there was a bug on github site.